# Bootstrap 3: Change order of MULTIPLE columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hello bootstrap community,

although I've tried for days now everything I could possibly imagine to swap multiple columns in bootstrap 3 using push and pull commands I can't get the md-screen size to work properly.

Here is code: http://jsbin.com/dipel/3/embed?html,css,output

**For xs-size (no problem):**
All boxes  get full screen-width
Box1
Box2
Box3
Box4

**For sm-size (no problem):**
The last two boxes are swapped and beside each other
Box1
Box2
Box4 | Box3

**For md-size (no idea how to swap this):**
Here is my problem. I can't get this layout to swap positions properly.
Box1 | Box3
Box4 | Box2

Therefore my question: Is this layout generally possible with bootstrap 3 and if yes, how exactly?
Any ideas how to solve this?

Many thanks in advance

Stefan

Here is the my code example: http://jsbin.com/dipel/3/embed?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using 2 separate rows, then using col-md-6 (which would be 50% of the overall container).

For example:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box1"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box2"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box3"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="box4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a demo:

http://jsbin.com/tuhiqoda/1/edit

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort and your quick reply. Unfortunately in your sample code the box-order stays 1-2#3-4 in the md-size. My difficult goal here is to get 1-3#4-2 and for me this seems to be impossible without duplicating box3 and hiding this in a smaller screen-size. Do you think this is possible in bootstrap 3?

Comment: Unfortunately, as far as I know, you could only push and pull on the same row.

You could hide all 4 at col-md and create a separate one with that layout, which it sounds like you already know how to do. Sorry about misunderstanding your question in it's entirety.

Comment: ok, nevertheless I'll mark the question as solved then. If anyone else has another workaround for that, I'm very interested to know about.